# Screen dimmed upon wake after standby

Tags: intel-graphics, dell, brightness, screen

Sometimes upon resuming from standby I find my screen brightness dimmed to the lowest setting, even though the indicator says it's where I left it.

If I use my brightness function keys I get the popup notification showing me where I am on the scale, but there is no difference between the brightest and the dimmest.

Laptop: Dell XPS M1210, integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: me too, man. HP Compaq nc2400

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards